# Актуально ли использование RibbonWindow сейчас?

Tags: wpf, ribbon

При использовании `Ribbon`, в подавляющем большинстве примеров предлагают заменить `Window` на `RibbonWindow`. По крайней мере в Win10, это приводит к неприглядному виду окна.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может я чего-то не то делаю?

Comment: пробовали добавить манифест? https://habrahabr.ru/post/230505/

Comment: с MSDN: "RibbonWindow Представляет окно, которое может нарисовать панель быстрого доступа ленты и группы контекстных вкладкок в своих границах    " Если вам эти свойства/возможности нужны, то тогда переопределяйте дизайн RibbonWindow так, чтобы он выглядел как вам нужно. Если эти свойства вам не нужны-используйте стандартное окно.